# Как уменьшить размер картинки?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Добавляю в `ImageView` картинку из библиотеки. И так как как фото много весит это грузит приложение.

Как снизить качество фото для отображаемого View-элемента? Есть наработки у кого то?

Нашел в туториалах такое решение и не могу понять какие компоненты использовать.

Что нужно для полей : `getResources()`, `R.id.myimage` ,`reqHeight`, `reqWidth`.

В тоториале говорится:

> getResources() The resources object containing the image data
>
> R.id.myimage   The resource id of the image data

Но что бы это могло значить? E меня есть только url картинки и View.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;


// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы картинку с интернета грузите?.. Если да, то используйте готовые библиотеки типа UIL. Они загружают картинку и устанавливают ей размеры соответственно размерам контейнера для их отображения.

Comment: Нет я беру картинку с библиотеки на телефоне.

Comment: Если у вас есть адрес картинки (пути файла), то помянутая библиотека это тоже может. И с `ContentProvider` тоже.

Comment: А вообще, не понятно - что значит `беру картинку с библиотеки на телефоне`

Comment: Получаю url на картинку которая хранится на телефоне. Передаю этот  url в ImageView. Там она открывается но полноразмерная и весит 10 мегабайт(к примеру). Если создам пару таких ImageView то приложение повиснет

Comment: Мне надо как-то сдалать чтобы отображаемая картинка весила по меньше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте отечественную разработку [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). После её настройки согласно инструкции по ссылке процесс загрузки будет выглядеть так:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

При этом, если вы жёстко зададите параметры высоту/ширины `ImageView`, то библиотека сама уменьшит размеры картинки до размеров контейнера. Т.е., если, например у вас есть картинка 1000х1000 пикселей, а `ImageView` у вас размерами в 30х30 пикселей, то библиотека в процессе загрузки уменьшит изображение до 30х30 пикселей.
Вы можете это проверить получив `Bitmap` из `ImageView` и получив его параметры.

---

Подобных библиотек множество. Из последних - [fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) от лицоКниги. Они тоже, наверняка это могут, но, я лично не проверял.

Comment: Да дельная библиотека. Спасибо... Но что-то у меня ни чего не отображается...Это правено для тефолта?   Я ничего не забыл?     `ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        imageLoader.displayImage(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), imageView);`

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к строке-пути что то типа `file:///` в её начало

Comment: Спасибо. Очень выручили. Помогло.

Comment: Столкнулся со странным глюком. На виртуальном телефоне(genymoution) все картинки одинаковые, а именно иконка андройд...Что бы это могло значить?

Comment: @BogdanShulga, только при использовании библиотеки или во всех случаях?.. На каком-то этапе, видать, файл ваш не находится и вместо него где-то проставляется заглушка. Может и в эмуляторе глюк. Кто знает?..

Comment: Только при использовании библиотеки. Но на двух ревльных устройствах работает нормально. Переживаю что-бы на других девайсах баг не вылез

Comment: @BogdanShulga, посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/699). Пишут, что могут быть проблемы из-за всяких там пробелов в пути к файлу. Надо путь к файлу привести к виду, воспринимаемому UIL

Comment: Подскажите плз. Не хотят открываться ссылки типа `content://external/images/media/21296` В чтем может быть проблема? Дело в том что не могу получить полный путь на файлы в api >21 по этому хочу использовать ссылки content provider. Но они не открываются

Comment: Такие картинки не разу не пробовал грузить. Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/539)

Comment: Да как раз читаю :) Но пока ничего дельного не нашел. Спасибо.